# Вывод информации из mysql в таблицу столбцами

Tags: html, css

Написал код с постраничной навигацией, и выводом информации: фото - под фото ник

```
$q="SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY nick LIMIT $start,$per_page";
    $res = $connection->query($q);      
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo '<div class=profile-bd>';
        echo "<table>";

        echo "<tr><td align=center><br><a href='bd.php?act=nick_info&id=".$row['id']."'><img src='".$row['photo_url']."' width='150' height='150' alt='Фото пользователя'></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td align=center>".$row['nick']."<font color='#ffffff'></font></a></td></tr>";

        echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

проблема в том что выводится все в 1 столбец, я никак не могу понять как осуществить вывод информации в 3 или 4 столбца

[image: вывод информации из приведенного кода]

пожалуйста ткните носом где я не так делаю, хотелось бы видеть что то типа такого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблицами такое лучше не делать. Лучше сделать `div` со стилем

```
float:left
```

Comment: да действительно то что подсказали сработало, немного дописать пришлось и все получилось, таблицей я написал в том плане что в 1 ячейке, фото - отцентрировал, во 2 ячейке, ниже, ник - отцентрировал, если есть другой способ подскажите, дабы не табличить на странице буду благодарен

Comment: теми же блоками но без float: left и со свойством width: 100%